# Class as a variable type

Tags: java, object-reference

im a programming newbie studying computerscience in second semester. sorry for the german language program. but i hope it won't be a problem understanding it. it basically is about converting currencies.

My question is: what is the function of a class as  a variable/data type here? i mean in the class dm (deutsche mark) you have the constructor with the given parameter (Euro a). should i think of "a" as a new object of the class euro? or what is it exactly? i saw this kind of variables in many occasions, apparently it is quite common. i hope someone can help.

thanks!

Mel

```
public abstract class waehrung {
    public abstract double dollarBetrag();
}   

public class Euro extends waehrung {
    private static double kurs = 1;
    private double wert;

    public Euro(double wert){
        this.wert = wert; 
}

    public double dollarBetrag(){
        return wert*kurs;
    }

    public double euroBetrag(){
    return wert;
    }

    public static void setEuroKurs(double Kurs){
        kurs = kurs;
    }   
}

class DM extends Euro{
    public DM (double dm){      
        super(dm/1.95583);
    }

    public DM(Euro a){  
        super(a.euroBetrag());
    }   

    public double waehrungsBetrag() {
        return euroBetrag()*1.95583;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `DM` is a subclass of `Euro`, and in its constructor

```
public DM(Euro a){  
    super(a.euroBetrag());
}
```

it calls to `a.eurobetrag()` and pass it to the superclass constructor:

```
public Euro(double wert){
    this.wert = wert; 
}
```

therefore, `a` is not a variable of `DM` class, it's just used to get a value `a.euroBetrag()` and then assigns it to the attribute `wert`:

```
this.wert = wert;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think of `a` as an reference to an object of class `Euro`. It came from the code used to construct the `DM` object:

```
DM dm = new DM(euro);
```

where `euro` is a reference to some object of class `Euro`. In the constructor, this becomes `a`.

Comment: Don't start off thinking of it as an object. It's a reference. Better start using the proper terminology early on.

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> what is the function of a class as a variable/data type here? i mean
>   in the class dm (deutsche mark) you have the constructor with the
>   given parameter (Euro a). should i think of "a" as a new object of the
>   class euro? or what is it exactly? i saw this kind of variables in
>   many occasions, apparently it is quite common

```
 public DM(Euro a){  
        super(a.euroBetrag());
 }
```

Answer : `a` is a variable wich is type is Euro, so `a` (that is called reference) is referring to an Euro object. An Euro object in your example could be a `DM` or `Euro`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DM(Euro a){
```

`a` isn't a "new" object.  When the rest of the program uses this constructor, it will need to have an *existing* `Euro` object, like this:

```
Euro someEuroVariable;  // for example
...
DM d = new DM(someEuroVariable);
```

and the constructor will then use `someEuroVariable` as its parameter, which it refers to as `a`.  But no new `Euro` object is created by this.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** To answer the question in the comments: You can't say

```
DM d = new DM();
```

because `DM` doesn't have a constructor that you can use with no parameters.  But let's say you used a legal constructor like

```
DM d = new DM(1.234);
```

and now you say

```
Euro a = d;
```

`a` and `d` will be references to the *same* object.  This object has a *run-time* type of `DM`.  When you declare a variable `a` to have type `Euro`, that means that `a` can, during its lifetime, be an object of type `Euro` *or any of its subclasses*.  However, since the compiler can't tell what the actual type will be at runtime, you can only use a method `a.method()` if the method was defined for `Euro`.  If `DM` has a new method `method2` that `Euro` doesn't have, you can't call it directly with `a.method2()`.  It also means that later on, you could reassign `a` to an object with some other subclass:

```
a = new Lira(100000000000.0);
```

while you can't do that with `d` because it can only be of type `DM` or a subclass of `DM`:

```
d = new Lira(100000000000.0);  // Error at compile time
```

This distinction between compile-time type and run-time type can be difficult to grasp until you get used to it.  It's also totally unrelated to what happens when you pass a `Euro` as a parameter to a `DM` constructor; the object that you pass as a parameter is a separate object and must exist before the constructor is called.

Comment: but suppose i do the following referencing: DM d = new DM(); Euro a= d;   what happens after such a referencing? how is it actually possible to reference the object of a subclass using the superclass as a type? i know sublclass inherits from the superclass, still  doesn't help me understand..

Comment: yea you are right. the distinction is for me still far from clear.  But your answer to my question was very helpful. Thanks!!